# Tracking redirected subdomain hits with Analytics

Tags: analytics, qr-code

I've created a sticker with a QR code pointing to my website. I've set the QR code to point to subdomain called QR to be able to tell how many visitors came through the sticker. The qr subdomain is redirected to the main domain.

How do I set up tracking for the QR code ?
Is there a way I can track hits that came from that redirect in the past if I set it up now ?

Comment: Which analytics package are you using?

Comment: @TerenceEden Basic Google Analytics